# How are you supposed to see unassigned non-project tasks in Personal Projects in Asana?

Tags: asana

In the workspace created by Asana when I created my account, called Personal Projects, when I create a tasks that I don't assign to myself and I don't assign to a project, that task is very hard to find. I need to run an advance search to get to them.

Being that that is the default way of creating tasks, it looks like is very easy to let tasks fall through the cracks.

How am I supposed to see them? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

The Personal Projects workspace has been phased out in the newer versions of Asana. I learned this when I asked about a limitation I had with Personal Projects (it would not allow me to order projects within the workspace).

The Asana support team advised that I abandon the Personal Projects and create a new workspace. I used [this utility](https://asana.kothar.net/) to migrate my projects, and I was pleasantly surprised how well it worked.

Be sure to contact Asana support first to ask about this, if you haven't already.